# Using QStyle to set global default minimum QPushButton height

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to define a default minimum height for a `QPushButton` through a custom application wide `QStyle`?

I know this can be achieved using stylesheets, but I rather not use them because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider looking at the [`QApplication::globalStrut`](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qapplication.html#globalStrut-prop) property, which is designed to provide a minimum size for any user-interactive UI element.  Ideally, it would do what you want (and possibly more).  However, I have seen times when this was ignored, either by the widget or the style drawing the widget, so in practice it has been somewhat less than useful.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for, I'll try to see if it works for push buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options I can see, here they are:

1) Suclass QStyle and set it to your application using

```
QApplication::setStyle(QStyle* yourstyle)
```

In QStyle, you must reimplement your own

```
void QStyle::drawPrimitive ( PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption * option, QPainter * painter, const QWidget * widget = 0 ) const
```

2) Subclass QPushButton and use the method

```
QWidget::setMinimumHeight(int minHeight);
```

to set the minimum height and only use this subclass in the rest of your program.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is solution 1) going to work? Layouts need to know about the size as well, only drawing the widget at a certain size does not mean that the widget actually has that size. Solution 2) should work but is cumbersome :( I'll stick with hardcoding all sizes in the UI files for now.